# parse a string with multiple delimiters

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing

I have a list of files:

```
my_list = ['identification_2442942_23.txt', 'identification_9353289532_133.txt', 'identification_1321_9.txt']
```

How can I parse these all at once to obtain just the second number in each (the number after the second '_' and before the '.')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with a list comprehension.

```
>>> my_list = ['identification_2442942_23.txt', 'identification_9353289532_133.txt', 'identification_1321_9.txt']
>>> [i[i.rfind('_') + 1:i.rfind('.')] for i in my_list]
['23', '133', '9']
```

Naturally you could apply `int()` in the comprehension if you need them as integers.

Comment: this is more pythonic and elegant, and so I'll up vote it. I went with something more comprehensible to someone with a basic question, but this gets style points.

Comment: @ShawnMehan Thanks, I find that I simply can't get enough of comprehensions, they're so concise and readable at the same time.  I think they may be my favorite thing about the Python language.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the numbers out:

```
import re

def get_numbers(list):
    out = []
    for l in list:
        matched = re.match(r'\w+_\d+_(\d+)\.txt', l)
        if matched:
            out.append(matched.group(1))
    return(out)


my_list = ['identification_2442942_23.txt', 'identification_9353289532_133.txt']
numbers = get_numbers(my_list)
```